libvlc trying to play a rtsp of playback of a stream
I am currently working on a function to download playbacks of rtsp cameras (windows and linux).
The following is the code I used to open and download the stream:
void VLCStream::streamFunction(const char* rtsp_url) {
 media = libvlc_media_new_location(m_pVLC, rtsp_url);
 mediaPlayer = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(media);
 QString outputFile = m_cfgServer.strTempPath + '/' +
      m_qstrID + m_qstrTimeStamp + ".mp4";
 QString soutOption = ":sout=#duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=" + outputFile + "}}";
 libvlc_media_add_option(media, soutOption.toStdString().c_str());
 libvlc_media_add_option(media, ":rtsp-tcp");
 if (libvlc_media_player_play(mediaPlayer) != 0)
 {
  std::cerr << "Failed to start playback" << std::endl;
 }
}

media, mediaPlayer, m_pVLC are all declared in the header file and m_pVLC is initialized in the constructor.
I've tried these with public rtsp urls and the live streaming seems to work just fin.
But whenever I tried switching to a playback rtsp it doesn't work. Although

"Failed to start playback"

is never printed anywhere, the download/playback just don't start,
and I printed out the logs to see:

live555 demux error: RTSP PLAY failed Bad "Range:" header

I tried capturing packets with Wireshark, and here are the results:

For the successful opening of the live stream using an media app (customed developed by someone):
enter image description here
For the successful opening of the playback stream using the media app:
enter image description here
For the failed opening of the playback stream using my code:
enter image description here

You can see that when doing live stream preview, the media app sends the PLAY requeqst with an extra '/' by the end of the rtsp url, and the range is npt=0.000-; for successful playback, the rtsp url is without '/' and npt is a valid int range; For my failed attempt to accessing the playback, the PLAY request looks like the live stream preview and npt=0.000-.
So I wonder, is it possible that my program is treating a playback stream as a live stream? If so, does libvlc provide any function or setting that I can specify the media player/vlc instance to play the rtsp in "playback mode"?
